# How to prevent the "other user" from appearing on the logon screen of a server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

[image]When I want to log into a server console (Server 2008 R2), I click Ctrl+Alt+Del and get "Other User" that I need to click before I get the log in box to add my credentials.  This wouldnt be so bad, but I want to use this server as a Citrix server and so far every user that tries to connect has to click other user before they can add thier own credentials..

Has anyone got any ideas on ewhat I can do to get this to go straight to the username and password without the extra click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everyones suggestions, I have finally worked out what it was.  During my server build I had run the following command to get rid of boot animations:

bcdedit /set bootux disabled

I was going to try to run a windows repair, so re-enabled the boot animations with:

bcdedit /set bootux standard

Next boot, no "Other user" prompt.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure this behavior in group policy or the local security policy. The setting that you're looking for is

`Computer Configuration > Windows settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > "Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried what you suggested, but still get 'Other User' bit to click (I have added a screenshot on the original post).

Comment: ...and I just tried to re-add it to see if it helped (it didnt)